# How to set up interaction between a flexdashboard and another shiny application embedded in tab in that flexdashboard only?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have built a flexdashboard to do analysis of some model results. And in one of the tabs of the flexdashboard, I have embedded a shiny application that will take user inputs and generate the model results.  I have used the following feature of the flexdashboard.

basically, what i am trying to do is capture the output of the model results from this shiny application that runs within flexdashboard and pass it on the flexdashboard as a reactive object so it can do the analysis and display results in other tabs.

```
shinyAppDir(
  system.file("examples/06_tabsets", package="shiny"),
  options = list(height=850)
)
```

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html#external_applications

Comment: You can collect user inputs, run your model and display results in flexdashboard.  Why embed a shiny app?

Comment: @SteveM - it’s my understanding that for flexdashboard, user inputs will be captured in sidebar only and I am using that space for providing filters to analyze results in other tabs. So I thought to embed a separate shiny app with user inputs  for running the model.  

Unless I am missing some obvious way to Achieve this